# how to compare the current date with the input date in java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm using `cleandersonlobo:date-picker-materialize` package to input the date and I want to display an `alert("expired")` if the input date is less than the current date.

```js
var $strDate = $(".pmt-date").val();
var $dtDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $strDate);
var $strToday = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date());
var $tDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $strToday);

if ($dtDate < new Date()) {
  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
  alert("Job expired");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
var $strDate = $(".pmt-date").val();
var $dtDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $strDate);
var $strToday = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date());
var $tDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $strToday);

if ($dtDate < $strToday ) {
  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
  alert("Job expired");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `toMidnight` function that sets the time of a date to midnight and by doing so removes time as a factor for your comparison:

```
function toMidnight(date) {
  var midnight = arguments.length > 0 ? new Date(date) : new Date();
  midnight.setHours(0);
  midnight.setMinutes(0);
  midnight.setSeconds(0);
  midnight.setMilliseconds(0);
  return midnight;
}
```

Then you can compare your date like this:

```
toMidnight($dtDate) < toMidnight()
```